# External Hard Disk cannot be formatted after dd command on Mac OS

Tags: mac, partitioning, external-hard-drive

I was trying to create a bootable disk to install Windows 10 on one of my PCs.
I was doing it on my Mac using a 500GB external hard disk.

This is the command I have used on the Terminal to change the Windows 10 ISO to an IMG.

```
sudo dd if=./Win10_1511_SingleLang_English_x32.img.dmg of=/dev/rdisk2 bs=1m
```

Now when I try to open the Disk Utility to format the hard disk and to get the storage back I get an error. It is also only reading 2.9GB instead of 500 and seems like it's not seen as a storage disk at all.

How do I get my 500GB hard disk back? :)

Thanks for any suggestion

Comment: First, be ***100% sure*** that `/dev/rdisk2` is the proper device. With that done, try using the same `sudo dd...` command you used immediately, but substitute `if=/dev/zero` for the `.dmg` file you used in the first place. This won't make the disk immediately useable, but it *should* make it possible for Disk Utility to make it useable.